# Upgrade from Android 7.0 to 9.0 in Asus Zenpad 10

Tags: 7.0-nougat

I have an Asus ZenPad 10 P028 and it has Android 7.0.
I was wondering is a good idea to upgrade to Android 9.0 and also is it feasible?

I've seen there are tutorials to move to LineageOS but it will not support my tablet version.

The reason to upgrade is that the android version I've is not stable, some apps crash unexpectedly and is not the fastest.

I'm not sure as I've read in other questions if the kernel would support the device.

What would you recommend?

Comment: New Android 9 is not faster than Android 7. If your device does not show you available updates then there are no updates to newer Android versions. Check Settings -> System-> Updates.

Comment: Hello Angelo. Our site focuses on questions which can be answered objectively. Open ended questions such as "what/how was your experience with XYZ", "Do you think I should do ABC", "What do you recommend given DEF issues/constraints" are not a good fit. They just keep inviting answers with opinions given their nature.